# Get Rank based on topscore of users laravel mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel

I executed the following query to get the topscore of users in a current week and got the below result from database

```
SELECT u.id
     , u.firstName
     , u.lastName
     , MAX(s.score) total_score 
  FROM users u
  JOIN game_scores s
    ON s.user_id = u.id 
 WHERE s.created_at between '2020-02-23 00:00:00' AND '2020-02-28 09:10:50' 
 GROUP 
    BY u.id 
 ORDER 
    BY total_score DESC 
     , u.firstName ASC 


id  firstName lastName  total_score     
19  Cat        Rat         80
33   Rose       Jack       80
43   Stuart     Little     73
```

I want to get rank based on ascending order of user's first name like below :

```
id  firstName lastName  total_score  rank   
19   Cat       Rat         80         1
33   Rose       Jack       80         2
43   Stuart     Little     73         3
```

I am using it in Laravel like below but I am not getting the rank like above

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->join('game_scores', 'users.id', '=', 'game_scores.user_id')
    ->select('users.ids', 'users.firstName', 'users.lastName', DB::raw('MAX(game_scores.score) as total_score'))
    ->whereBetween('game_scores.created_at',[$start_date, date('Y-m-d h:i:s')])
    ->groupBy('users.id', 'users.firstName', 'users.lastName')
    ->orderBy('total_score', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

The above query gives me only users with high scores in current week.Need to get their rank also accordingly.

Comment: What is the output of your query? Also please check your query using  `DB::enableQueryLog(); //your query query dd(DB::getQueryLog())`

Comment: Is rank not actually a db field? you could render it once you've fetched the result

Comment: you can use a variable to keep increment the number as a rank or you can DENSE_RANK function to rank it based on score or firstname.

Comment: Seems like an unfair way to rank results :-(  - and how does Tom Cruise become Cat Rat?

Comment: sorry editing mistake . updated